# QGIS 3.18 - Save form field value into variable

Tags: qgis, python

I'm trying to find a way to store a value from a QGIS form field into a QGIS project variable. Is it something possible ?

I have a postgreSQL table and a QGIS form made from the fields of that table. What I'm trying to do is once the form has been submitted, the value of the `id` field is stored into a QGIS project variable to be used in another form.

If that's not possible using the default QGIS forms functionality, can it be implemented using python ? I didn't find any documentation about working with forms and python.

Comment: Forms are mostly handled by Qt, check the Qt documentation. The Form corresponds to a Python object, which has properties with the widgets of Form. Different widgets have different methods to get the content (e.g. text, currentText, etc).